# Excel Scatterplot Graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

How would I put on set of data on the x axis and the other on the y in Excel?

Meaning suppose I had 5 people rate two different films on a scale of 10 and I organized my results like this:

```
Person   Film 1    Film 2
1        5         9
2        7         4
3        3         7
4        9         2
5        1         6
```

How would I graph this in excel such that Film 1 is on the x axis and Film 2 is on the y axis (or vice-versa)?

The problem is that on an XY scatter, the y axis holds both the data for Film 1 and Film 2 (while the x is the person number). And if I put Film 1 in the y axis and Film 2 in the X axis, then it only shows the values for Film 1 plotted on the y axis (with film 2 on the x axis just being the range). I have not been able to get all the values for Film 1 and Film 2 plotted against each other.

I've tried looking online to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "Not the actual HW Question" mean? Have you tried just creating an XY ("Scatter") chart? It's not that hard.

Comment: Meaning I didn't copy it word for word, made a new table and situation up. Need to know the concept, not the answer to a HW Question. 
Yes I have tried XY scatterplot, but all that does is put both Film 1 and Film 2 on the y axis, with the people number on the x axis.

Comment: Oh, so "HW" means homework.. You should tell us what you've tried and where your problem is. Please [edit] and update your question with this info. In that case, your x and y axes are film 1 and 2, not the person, so you just select film 1 and 2 as data.

Answer (score 3):

First, highlight the Film1 and Film2 data, including the title:
[image]

next, select X-Y scatter from the *insert charts* menu. This should produce a graph that has the values you want, just needing some tidying up:
[image]